# USPS Address Validation Fail

Tags: c#, xml, usps

When validating an address, I get this error:

```
ex = {"Error Loading XML:  The following tags were not closed: AddressValidateRequest, Address, Address1.\r\n"}
```

or I get another error saying the address cannot be found. Is there a better way to validate this address?

Here is my URL:

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="402JMAWE3481"><Address ID="1"><Address1>123 Main St</Address1><Address2></Address2><City>Watertown</City><State>MA</State><Zip5>02472</Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>
```

Comment: Please do not edit this question to break the XML up over multiple lines as this is not what the OP is sending. The OP is sending the URL as a single line. If you need to see whether or not the [XML is "valid" on its own please see the following dump](http://pastie.org/4052770).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>According what I see on the error description, the problem could be that you need to remove `\r\n` from the xml before adding it to the url</strike>. Don't forget also to url encode it.

Comment: I had originally edited the URL to accurately reflect what the OP was sending to the server, however, ErikPhilips added the newlines...But +1 for "Url encode it".

Comment: I needed to remove the # sign if I said 123 Main St #41, so there was an encoding issue. Also, the street address should go on address 2 while the apt # goes on address 1

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to HtmlEncode it and then UrlEncode it.
This is becasue you're actually sending XML (which requires `&amp;` instead of `&`) but its a URL so it needs encoding to make each `&` into `%26`

Here's a complete working URL - you just need to put in your USERID.

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="123USERID567"><Address ID="1"><Address1></Address1><Address2>10051+Orr+%26amp%3b+Day+Rd</Address2><City>santa+fe+springs</City><State>ca</State><Zip5>90670</Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>
```

You'll see it contains this funky looking string:

```
 10051+Orr+%26amp%3b+Day+Rd
```

Which I got by doing this :

```
 HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("10061 Orr & Day Rd"))
```

[This specific error I got back when I didn't encode properly was `Error Loading XML:  Whitespace is not allowed at this location`]